# Parsing XML on Android

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

There are lots of tips to parse complicated XML but I want a parse for simple XML like:

```
<map>
     <string name="string_1">Hello there</string>
     <string name="string_2">This is Mium.</string>
</map>
```

I was trying to use SAXParser (I'm not sure which to use: SAXParser or XMLPullParser), so I'm looking at [Parse XML on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420835/parse-xml-on-android)

```
public void ParseData(String xmlData)
{
    try
    {
        // Document Builder
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Input Stream
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));

        // Parse Document into a NodeList
        Document doc = db.parse(inStream);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");

        // Loop NodeList and Retrieve Element Data
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);

            if (node instanceof Element)
            {
                Element child = (Element)node;
                String id = child.getAttribute("id");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SAXException e)
    {

    }
    }
```

However, it's already complicated XML parse.
How should I code only to parse ?

Comment: Have you read about official suggested `XMLPullParser`? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

Comment: [refer this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm)

Comment: @HardikVasani it helped a lot. thanks.

Comment: @Mium welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Your loop should look like this:

Node node = nList.item(i);
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
{
     Element element = (Element) node;
     tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nName : " + getValue("name", element)+"\n");
}
```

where getValue :

```
private static String getValue(String tag, Element element)
{
   NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
   Node node = nodeList.item(0);
   return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a LOT.